# How we can deploy or host our JSON-SERVER API?

Tags: reactjs, api, json-server, wordpress-json-api

I have implemented one react template with static data for learning purpose only. And deployed in github. For data I have created one json file in directory. But this file is not reacted as a API, Means I can't perform post, put and filter queries.

**REACT TEMPLATE:**
https://pesitvarun.github.io/react/#/

Now I am planning to host or deploy JSON data and make API. I got one solution through https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server But it is running in local server, I want to deploy in globally So I can fetch from anywhere. So Now I deployed my dummy page on git so anyone can see my template. Like this I want to deploy json and make API call and render all data to this template screens. 
please suggest your idea about API hosting or deployment. So I can render data through api.

Comment: there are many ways to deploy a service here is one that is free for 1 project. It is called https://github.com/jesperorb/json-server-heroku